# Multiple rootviewcontrollers in the sam iphone app?

Tags: iphone

is it possible to make use of 2 rootviewcontrollers in a app?if it is possible how to push and pop between rootviewcontroller's?
is the function pushviewcontroller:secondrootviewcontroller valid?

Answer (score 1):

A so-called rootviewcontroller can be assigned to UIWindow objects or UINavigationControllers.

- Applications are expected to have a key-window with a designated rootviewcontroller at application launch, e.g. `window.rootViewController = someController;`.
- If you want to change the rootviewcontroller in a navigationcontroller, there are 2 ways:

  1. create a new navigation-controller replacing the old instance
  2. use the method `-(void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated;` to replace the viewcontroller-array of the navigationcontroller.